# jwplayer slow on triggering "onReady" event

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

It takes in average around ten seconds in Firefox (if I clean my browser cache), for jwplayer to kick in. That is the time span from when jwplayer's setup() is executed until it triggers its "onReady" event. If I do not load jwplayer's xml skin the delay can be avoided, but why should loading of xml skin cause such a long delay? I even see this delay when I load the following sample page on my localhost.

Sample page: http://sandbox.saeidmohadjer.com/jwplayer.php

Look at console for a log of time it takes.

Thanks

Comment: I would update to 6.6, it only took me 4325 ms for the player to be ready though, which seems fine.